# Manually set package as installed in Python/pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm installing the `openbabel` package, and it can automatically generate the necessary Python libraries during compilation. This saves a good chunk of time, since installing from source via `pip` takes a few minutes, and that time can be rolled into the initial compilation.

I've listed it as a requirement in my `requirements.txt` file, but when I go to install (`pip install -r requirements.txt`), it attempts to reinstall the `openbabel` Python library. When I run `pip show` or `pip list`, `openbabel` doesn't show up.

Is there a way to manually mark a package as installed so pip thinks it's installed, even if it can't find the package? Or is there a file I can create that pip will use that will tell it `openbabel` is installed?

Comment: if a package has been installed an it's in the `site-packages` directory pip should show you `requirement already satisfied`. i suspect you've installed openbabel but for the wrong version of python, and you're invoking pip for a different version

Comment: openbabel is installed in site-packages for the version of python I'm using. It's not installed like a normal package, it's installed by copying the files like `make install` does.

Comment: well since you know openbabel is installed you could simply 'black list' it by removing it from the `requirements.txt` file

Comment: @danidee That doesn't help when the package he wants to skip is a transitive dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty .egg-info file in your site-packages directory.

For example, on my machine I did `touch /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/GLWindow-1.8.0-py3.6.egg-info` to trick pip3 into thinking that I've installed `GLWindow`.